# Incorrect permissions for file with docker compose volume? 13: Permission denied

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, docker-compose, permission-denied

I have the following docker_compose.yaml:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: nginx:1.17.10
    container_name: reverse_proxy
    volumes:
      - ../nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - "8050:8050"
      - "8051:8051"
  webapp:
    image: my-site
    command: --port 8050 8051 --debug yes
    volumes:
      - /home/user/data:/data
    ports:
      - "8050:8050"
      - "8051:8051"
    depends_on:
      - reverse-proxy
```

When I run via docker compose I get the following error:

```
$ sudo docker-compose -f /home/user/docker_compose.yaml up
...
reverse_proxy    | 2022/03/09 00:49:19 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (13: Permission denied)
reverse_proxy    | nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (13: Permission denied)
reverse_proxy exited with code 1
```

So to investigate I re-ran *just* the nginx container:

```sh
$ sudo docker run -v ../nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t docker.io/nginx tail -f /dev/null
```

`ssh`'d in and I see:

```
root@d8e84f89fcad:/# ls -la /etc/nginx/
ls: cannot access '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf': Permission denied
total 20
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root  132 Mar  1 14:00 .
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   66 Mar  9 00:54 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   26 Mar  1 14:00 conf.d
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1007 Jan 25 15:03 fastcgi_params
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 5349 Jan 25 15:03 mime.types
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   22 Jan 25 15:13 modules -> /usr/lib/nginx/modules
-?????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? nginx.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  636 Jan 25 15:03 scgi_params
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  664 Jan 25 15:03 uwsgi_params
```

I consulted the [following Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52195175/strange-file-permission-in-docker-container-question-marks-on-permission-bit-an) and others and they seem to suggest to just restart the docker service, so I did and I still get `?` permissions upon re running.

I assume that this is causing the permission error? If so, how can I set the correct permissions on this nginx config file? Is this really a volume permission issue?

Versions:

```
Docker version 1.13.1, build 7d71120/1.13.1
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c
CentOS 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was an SELinux thing, appending `:z` to the volume fixed it.

```yaml
volumes:
      - ../nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:z
```

Comment: I am afraid this didn't help me. I am using a weird combination of things. Git and one submodule from which I am taking one folder and mount it as a volume to nginx-certbot and apparently Amazon AWS (Elastics Beanstalk) is doing something weird there, something I can't reproduce locally. But I ended up having to use a custom Dockerfile for nginx-certbot loaded from docker-compose.yml in which I copy the folder content manually and run `RUN chmod -R 775 /path/to/the/folder/in/docker`. I am not too fond of that sadly, but the only thing I was able to come up with so far which also worked to me.